# Disable root login for dropbear?

Tags: ssh, centos6, root, dropbear

Linux noob here. How can I disable root login for dropbear?
What I've done so far

- adding DROPBEAR_EXTRA_ARGS="-w -g" into /etc/default/dropbear (not working)
- adding DROPBEAR_EXTRA_ARGS="-w -g" into /etc/init.d/dropbear (not working too)

Dropbear version dropbear-0.58-1.el6.i686.rpm installed on centos 6.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using Dropbear and not OpenSSHd?

Comment: Sorry, this just popped straight to my mind.. have you restarted the dropbear service?

Comment: Do those options actually get added to the process when it's restarted?  You can check with `ps -ef | grep dropbear`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on looking at the /etc/init.d/dropbear script from dropbear-0.58-1.el6.i686.rpm I'd say you need to have the following line in the config file /etc/sysconfig/dropbear:

```
OPTIONS=-w -g
```

After modifying the file, restart the dropbear service. If all goes well, using `ps -efw | grep dropbear` should show that the options have really been passed to the executable.